# MockMVC formLogin authentication... and business actions

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

This test won't work: POST request isn't authenticated

`@Test
    public void testSecuredPostEntity() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(formLogin().user("test").password("test"))
                .andExpect(authenticated().withUsername("test").withRoles("ADMIN"));
        mockMvc.perform(post("/authors")
                .content("{\"name\":\"toto\",\"birth\":\"2016-01-01\"}")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(authenticated()) // FAILURE no authentication
            .andExpect(status().isOk()) // 403 here if above commented
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", notNullValue()))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.createdBy", is("test")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.createdDate", notNullValue()));
        mockMvc.perform(logout())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }`

Does anyone know how do I keep authenticated when performing such a request, please?

Comment: did you apply springSecurity() to your MockMvcBuilder ?

Comment: No... do you have an example? I'm using Spring boot's @AutoConfigureMockMvc and "secure=true" doesn't change a thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it:

```
    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(formLogin().user("test").password("test"))
            .andExpect(authenticated().withUsername("test")
                                      .withRoles("ADMIN"))
            .andReturn();
    MockHttpSession session = (MockHttpSession) mvcResult.getRequest().getSession(false);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/authors")
            .session(session)
            .content("{\"name\":\"toto\",\"birth\":\"2016-01-01\"}")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Comment: I still have a 403 issue, thought.

`MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 403
    Error message = Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.
          Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}`

Comment: And got error 400 when used `http.csrf().disable();` in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure

Comment: Ok then, the 403 is fixed, error 400 must come from Date format

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment reply, it seems you doesn't apply any special things to your `MockMvcBuilders`, so I assume you use the standaloneSetup or webAppContextSetup without further options.

In order to do security aware integration test, you first should enable springSecurity() on webAppContextSetup (AFAIK it only works with this setup), like this:

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
```

This turns on security back again (for normal integration tests, security is off).

Now, you just can use the `@WithMockUser` annotation to enable a custom user authentication:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "test", roles = {"ADMIN"})
public void testSecuredPostEntity() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/authors")
                .content("{\"name\":\"toto\",\"birth\":\"2016-01-01\"}")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(authenticated()) // FAILURE no authentication
            .andExpect(status().isOk()) // 403 here if above commented
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", notNullValue()))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.createdBy", is("test")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.createdDate", notNullValue()));
}
```

***note: you need org.springframework.security:spring-security-test dependency for these features***

Comment: Thanks David, but this appears to be irrelevant in this context as secure mode is setup by default when AutoConfigureMockMvc annotation is used.
@WithMockUser is a good point, thought, and it works like a charm, avoiding me to suffer the login boilerplate code. Have a good day